# Image to set at right

Tags: asp.net, css

In the below code i have a dropdown list and a image .In my case the dropdown list and image are very closer but i want the image to be at some distance to right. i set align to right and it set few distance.pls help me to solve the issue.
css:

```
.custom-combobox {
    position: relative;
    display: inline-block;
    height:35px;
    width:90px;
  }
  .custom-combobox-toggle {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    margin-left: -1px;
    padding: 0;
    /* support: IE7 */
    *height: 1.7em;
    *top: 0.1em;
  }
  .custom-combobox-input {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0.3em;
     height:35px;
      width:90px;
        font-size:small;
  }
   .style11
  {
      width: 63px;
  }
```

asp.net:

```
<td >
       <asp:DropDownList ID="cbAutoList" runat="server">
       <asp:ListItem Value="gmas"></asp:ListItem>
        <asp:ListItem Value="gmas1"></asp:ListItem>
         <asp:ListItem Value="gmas2"></asp:ListItem>
          <asp:ListItem Value="gmas3"></asp:ListItem>
           <asp:ListItem Value="gmas4"></asp:ListItem>
            <asp:ListItem Value="gmas5"></asp:ListItem>
            </asp:DropDownList>

        </td>

        <td class="style11">
           <asp:Image ID="imgAutoList" ImageAlign="Right" ImageUrl="images\error.jpg" runat="server" /> 
        </td>
```

Comment: try this `.style11 {width:300px; text-align:right;}` if this doesn't work then add this: `.style11 img { margin-left:auto; }`

Answer (score 0):

ImageAlign Right will position the image to the right of the element its inside, im not sure what the dimensions of your image error.jpg are but if you increase the size of the td (eg .style11{width: 100px;}) the image should move further away. Can you supply a screenshot or link if this is not the case?